# Check for new mail without Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, notifications, notification-area

Is there an application that will allow me to be notified of new email received via Exchange, without having Outlook started? Basically I want to know when I receive new email without having Outlook running, and then, start Outlook if I find it necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [OWANotify](http://www.owanotify.com/features.asp) which is freeware. It checks your Exchange account for new mail via the WebDAV protocol.

[image]

Comment: This one is OK but it doesn't seem to support proxy with authentication. Says something about using the proxy settings from IE, but it does not actually get through.

Comment: SmartMail Notifier is actually further away then what I am looking for because it does not support the Exchange format. OWANotify is almost there, I'll probably contact them in regards to proxy authentication.